# How to include a PHP Framework / Library in my module?

Tags: composer

I wanted to include PHPExcel.php in a testing module. So I put this file and the rest of the lib into:
`sites/all/libraries/phpexcel/`
and I used this in my module:

```
function mymod_libraries_info() {

$libraries['phpexcel'] = array(
'name' => 'PHP Excel',
'version arguments' => array(
  'file' => 'PHPExcel.php', // Could be any file with version info 
  'pattern' => '/Version (\d+)/', 
  'lines' => 5,
),
'files' => array(
  'php' => array('PHPExcel.php'), 
),
);
return $libraries;
}
```

But after a:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
```

I get a:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel' not found in sites/all/modules/mymod/mymod.module on line 81

Should be an easy inclusion somewhere? But where and how?

I found a `composer.json` as well along with the PHPExcel Lib - should I rather try to install composer_manager and try to get the composer installation working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't mention whether you have the Libraries module installed or not - that's kind of an important piece of information. It's not enough just to write hook_libraries_info() because that hook is used only by the Libraries module. If Libraries is not installed, it will do nothing. The Libraries module has good documentation to show how to use your class from a Drupal module. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/libraries-api-7x (or the equivalent D8 version - you don't say which version of Drupal you're using ...)